# Drawing a tangent line to a specific point of a surface?

Tags: plotting

I am new at *Mathematica* and I am really confused about drawing a tangent lines and surfaces issues.  My teacher wants me to draw a tangent line to specific point of a surface.

The surface equation is $z=x^2 + 2 x y$;  the point is (1,3,7)
and he wants me to draw a 3 tangent lines which are passing through the that point on $z = x^2 + 2 x y$ surface. He also want to see $z$ surface on the graphic at the same time.

If I am not wrong I've just plotted surface and that point but the tangent lines are still not included correctly:

```
    F[x_, y_] := x^2 + 2*x*y
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], Mesh -> False], 
  Graphics3D[Point[Table[{1, 3, 7}]]]]]
```

Could anyone can help me for the *Mathematica* code for this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, a little bit of theory [here](http://math.etsu.edu/multicalc/prealpha/Chap3/Chap3-6/printversion.pdf).

After that it's just typing it in. 
Here is a version, where you can drag the point to wherever you want.
It uses, [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) for your surface, [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) with [`InfiniteLine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html) to draw the lines and a [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) to draw the tangent-plane.

```
Slider2D[Dynamic[p],{{-4,-4},{4,4}}]
Dynamic[
dx=p[[1]];dy=p[[2]];
anchorPoint={dx,dy,dx^2+2*dx*dy};
anchorRules=MapThread[Rule,{{x,y,z},anchorPoint}];
xsol=(D[{x,y,(x^2+2*x*y)},x]/.anchorRules);
ysol=(D[{x,y,(x^2+2*x*y)},y]/.anchorRules);
Show[
Plot3D[x^2+2*x*y,{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4},PlotStyle->Opacity[0.3,Blue],ImageSize->900],
Graphics3D[{Black,PointSize[Large],Point[anchorPoint],Thick,InfiniteLine[{anchorPoint,anchorPoint+xsol}],InfiniteLine[{anchorPoint,anchorPoint+ysol}],InfiniteLine[{anchorPoint,anchorPoint+ysol+xsol}],InfiniteLine[{anchorPoint,anchorPoint+ysol-xsol}]}],
ParametricPlot3D[anchorPoint+x*xsol+y*ysol,{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10},PlotStyle->Opacity[0.1,Red]]
,PlotRange->{{-4,4},{-4,4},{-20,50}}]
]
```

Or animated:

[image]

With [`InfinitePlane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfinitePlane.html) as suggested by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129784/drawing-a-tangent-line-to-a-specific-point-of-a-surface/129786?noredirect=1#comment380988_129786) in the comments:

```
Slider2D[Dynamic[p], {{-4, -4}, {4, 4}}]
Dynamic[dx = p[[1]]; dy = p[[2]];
 anchorPoint = {dx, dy, dx^2 + 2*dx*dy};
 anchorRules = MapThread[Rule, {{x, y, z}, anchorPoint}];
 xsol = (D[{x, y, (x^2 + 2*x*y)}, x] /. anchorRules);
 ysol = (D[{x, y, (x^2 + 2*x*y)}, y] /. anchorRules);
 Show[Plot3D[x^2 + 2*x*y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3, Blue], ImageSize -> 900], 
  Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[Large], Point[anchorPoint], Thick, 
    InfiniteLine[{anchorPoint, anchorPoint + xsol}], 
    InfiniteLine[{anchorPoint, anchorPoint + ysol}], 
    InfiniteLine[{anchorPoint, anchorPoint + ysol + xsol}], 
    InfiniteLine[{anchorPoint, anchorPoint + ysol - xsol}], 
    Opacity[0.2, Red], 
    InfinitePlane[{anchorPoint, anchorPoint + xsol, 
      anchorPoint + ysol}]}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-20, 50}}]]
```

Comment: Neat visualization! I'll have to make note of it for demonstrations of my own!

Comment: `InfinitePlane[]` should be usable here as well.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I updated the anwser.

Comment: You can simplify `InfinitePlane[]` a bit: `InfinitePlane[anchorPoint, {xsol, ysol}]`.